# Отображение кириллицы в БД крокозябрами (НЕ вопросительные знаки)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, кириллица, xampp

Всем добрый день!

В БД полный ноль, поэтому прошу заранее простить, не кидать тапками и ответы давать "как для новичка".

Суть проблемы.

Есть Сайт. Стоит на локалке (XAMPP). Суть работы сайта - по нику находится аккаунт в инстаграм и потом по нему ведется статистика.

На сайте все работает отлично. Отображается и латинские буквы (сам ник и тп), и кириллица (описание к нику). Вся информация (и ник, и описание) подтягиваются из инстаграма. Сам я ничего не ввожу.

Но в базе данных к этому сайту (куда все сохраняется) в таблице instagram_users в колонках full_name и description (где должна быть информация об аккаунте на кириллице) вот такое отображение

Ð¢Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒÑÐ½Ð° Ð¢Ð¸Ð¼Ð¾Ñ„ÐµÐµÐ²Ð° 
â–ªï¸Ð“Ð°Ñ€Ð´ÐµÑ€Ð¾Ð±Ð½Ð°Ñ Ñ„ÐµÑ
â–ªï¸ÐšÐ¾Ð»ÑƒÐ¼Ð½Ð¸ÑÑ‚ SNC, Cosmo, Grazia, Lady Mail.Ru
â–ªï¸ÐžÐ½Ð»Ð°Ð¹Ð½-ÐºÑƒÑ€ÑÑ‹ ÑÑ‚Ð¸Ð»Ñ
ðŸ“© tt@shoppingschool.ru
ðŸŽ“ÐžÐ½Ð»Ð°Ð¹Ð½-ÑˆÐºÐ¾Ð»Ð° Ð¸ Ð‘Ð›ÐžÐ“â¤µï¸

Автоматические определители кодировок выдают, что это CP1252, но на выходе текст все равно не идеален (хотя намного лучше). Пполучается вот так

Тать�на Тимофеева 
▪��Гардеробна� фе�
▪��Колумни�т SNC, Cosmo, Grazia, Lady Mail.Ru
▪��Онлайн-кур�ы �тил�
 tt@shoppingschool.ru
Онлайн-школа и БЛОГ⤵��

При этом сама в самой странице сайте указано 
     `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Сама база создавалась в кодировке utf8mb4_unicode_ci

тип проблемных столбцов - varchar

Соответственно вопрос 
Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы все корректно отображалось и в самой бд (кириллица)? И как :)

Понимаю, что прошу многого, но если будете говорить, как делать, то огромная просьба писать не только что делать, но где и как.
Уверен, что это поможет многим новичкам в решении аналогичной проблемы (ибо нигде не нашел нормального пошагового описания как решить эту проблему :( )

Заранее спасибо!

UPD

Сервер баз данных 
Сервер: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP 
Тип сервера: MariaDB 
Соединение сервера: SSL не используется 
Версия сервера: 10.1.31-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution 
Версия протокола: 10 
Пользователь: root@localhost 
Кодировка сервера: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Веб-сервер 
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.1.16 
Версия клиента базы данных: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 ... 
PHP расширение: mysqli  curl  mbstring  
Версия PHP: 7.1.16

phpMyAdmin 
Информация о версии: 4.8.0, последняя стабильная версия: 4.8.2

Comment: Ошибка может быть абсолютно в любом месте. Нужно описать всё с самого начала и до самого конца, начиная с кода создания базы данных и загрузки данных в неё до кода вывода данных на страницу (или хотя бы скриншота phpmyadmin, если речь про phpmyadmin)

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу кодировку самой базы (phpMyAdmin), строку подключения к бд (пароль не интересует), кодировку самой страницы, на которой пытаетесь отобразить данные, либо записать. И тогда получите более точный ответ.

Comment: @andreymal  спасио за отклик. Я обновил первый пост. Добавил туда всю инфу из phpmyadmin.   Сама база создавалась в кодировке utf8mb4_unicode_ci . Касаемо загрузки данных в нее - я не знаю, как это посмотреть/проверить. При создании самой базы я выбрал кодировку, а потом загрузил в нее дамп, который шел с архивом. Разработчик на мои вопросы сказал, что по вопросам кириллицы ничем помочь не может. Вся информация (и ник, и описание) подтягиваются из инстаграма. Сам я ничего не ввожу. Код вывода на страницу -  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> Если это оно.

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц  Обновил первый пост. Добавил всю информацию. По поводы строки подключения к БД - как это посмотреть? Сайт на локалке.

Answer (score 1):

> Сама база создавалась в кодировке utf8mb4_unicode_ci

База может создаваться в одной кодировке, а приложение может обращаться к ней в другой кодировке. В скриптах, которые работают с БД, обычно указывается кодировка запросом "SET NAMES utf8mb4".

Распространенная ошибка. Если в настройках mysql-сервера кодировка по умолчанию не совпадает с нужной, а также не указана кодировка в вашем приложении, то они будут взаимодействовать в кодировке сервера. Поскольку приложение и читает и пишет в одной кодировке (Latin например), то в самом приложении вы разницы и не заметите, но phpmyadmin, настроенный на utf, покажет "кракозябры".

Решение. Изначально настроить utf кодировку в вашем приложении

Comment: Спасибо. Учитывая, что я начал с того, что я практически полный ноль в плане БД, то общий смысл я конечно понял, но ...  Смотрите, я не разработчик, я пользователь. И я понятия не имею, как настроить кодировку в приложении. Еще раз :) Есть скрипт. Не мой. Он вытягивает инфу из инсты по запрашиваемому логину и ведет по ней статистику. На сайте все прекрасно. Проблема только в 2 колонках БД, куда пишется инфа в кириллице (как и по какому принципу - я не знаю :( ).

Comment: Разработчик скрипта англоязычный и отвечает, что вопросы по кириллице выходят за рамки поддержки. Да и вообще - скрипт работает - значит все ок. Такие вот дела.   Добавил инфу в первый пост + в комментариях выше.

Comment: Чтобы отображалось корректно и в базу записывалось вам нужно чтобы были одинаковые кодировки в фронтенде (html странице), бэкэнде (php или что там у вас), подключении к базе (если это MySql то  mysql_set_charset($link, 'utf8');) ну и в самой базе сравнение (для UTF-8 у себя выставлял utf8_general_ci)

Comment: Если на сайте все ок, то попробуйте пхпмайадмин настроить на кодировку, в которой сохраняет скрипт

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц и на сайте UTF-8, и в БД Кодировка сервера: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8). 
Сопоставление кодировки соединения utf8mb4_unicode_ci.      А вот это "подключении к базе (если это MySql то mysql_set_charset($link, 'utf8');)" где и как проверить/выставить?

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov Скажите, пож-та, а как проверить в чем сохраняет? (хотя это пол беды, можно методом тыка)... И как настроить? И после смены кодировки в phpmyadmin не слетит ли латиница, которая сейчас отображается?

Comment: Поскольку разработчик англоязычный и не заморачивается с другими кодировками, то скорей всего это Code Page 1252 Windows Latin 1. Латиница не слетает, - это общий стандарт. Проблемы всегда с национальными буквами

Comment: @A M в mysql функция mysqli_set_charset(подключение, кодировка);

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц Спасибо за терпение. Если бы Вы еще подсказали, что мне делать с этой функцией :( Попробовал ввести в консоль - выдало ошибку :(

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц там скрипт чужой, от англоязычного разработчика. По традиции англоязычные разрабы часто не заморачиваются с другими кодировками

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov ДА, Вы правы, как я уже писал выше - автоопределитель кодировок выдал как раз CP1252 .  Теперь главный вопрос - как это исправить. только по шагам, если можно :(

Comment: Выполнил поиск по всем файлам скрипта (нотепадом), но mysqli_set_charset не нашел :(   Ощущение, что правда где-то рядом, но я ее не вижу в силу своей неопытности...

Comment: в открытом доступе есть эти скрипты? На гитхабе например?

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov  нет, это коммерческий скрипт с Envato с ограниченной лицензией :(